# Limitar criação de Ramais no Elastix 4

Tags: php

boa tarde. tenho um lastix 4 rodando como pabx mas preciso realizar uma modificação nele.

Quando chegar em 10 ramais o formulário de adicção tem q ser substituído pra uma mensagem customizada.

Já li e reli os arquivos não acho onde esta o template do formulário em questão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém que já mexeu com elastix poderia me orientar ?

Comment: Boa noite, você já acessou o [fórum deles](http://www.elastixbrasil.com.br/)? tem uma galera especializada lá inclusive um grupo de whatsapp.

Comment: ja postei no elastix brasil e no elastix.org e tbm ninguém me ajudou.
achei pelo menos onde fica a função que adiciona as informações no db, talvez eu bloqueie por la.